# iren AddObserver UserEvent {wm deiconify .vtkInteract} to python

Tags: python, tcl, vtk

I'm learning vtk with vtk user's guide. But the examples are basically all written in tcl. I am trying to learn to use vtk in python though.

I don't understand what the following code does:

`iren AddObserver UserEvent {wm deiconify .vtkInteract}`

It says "render the image". Could anyone explains this to me? and how this can be used in python with vtk? (iren is a vtkRenderWindowInteractor)

Also does the code

```
earth SetFileName "$VTK_DATA_ROOT/Data/earth.ppm"
```

mean earth.SetFileName("VTK_DATA_ROOT/Data/earth.ppm")? The dollar sign also confuses me.

Comment: I would avoid looking at the tcl examples. There are hundreds of c++ examples here: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx and many python examples as well: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Python

Answer (score 0):

The `iren AddObserver UserEvent` part is application-specific, but appears to be attaching code to something (`iren`?) to perform an action when a `UserEvent` fires, whatever that is.

The thing attached, `{wm deiconify .vtkInteract}` is pretty certainly a script to deiconify (i.e., make visible) a toplevel widget called `.vtkInteract` which will have been set up elsewhere in the code (explicitly or implicitly). The script is in quotes, so it's not for fully immediate execution, but is likely actually run as a callback when that action needs to be taken. While in general callbacks can have extra arguments passed to them (by suitable quoted concatenation, which works rather like using curried functions in other programming languages) that doesn't appear to be happening in this case.